# My email verification code is ok and and work correctly but printing the whole process from connection open to closing

Tags: php

In one of my project I worked with **PHP** to make a registration form complete with email verification and it works correctly but something unexpected is printing..It is printing the whole process from connection open to connection close..I there is anything in verification code that create no error logically but printing such odd thing..portion of this output is given in image bellow

**Here is my PHP code for email verification**

`
        //email varification starts here
        if($name == "" || $email == "" || $password != $cPassword || !empty($radioMsg)){
            $msg = "Please check your inputs";
        }else{
            $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

```
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                $msg = "Email already exist";
            }

            else{
                    //$token = md5(uniqid());
                    $token = '[*HIDE*YOUR*API*KEY*]';
                    $token = str_shuffle($token);
                    $token = substr($token, 0, 10);
                    $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
                    $con->query("INSERT INTO users (name,email,password,isEmailConfirmed,token,contact,status) VALUES ('$name','$email','$hashedPassword','0','$token','$contactNO','$radio')");

                    include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
                    include_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
                    include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
                    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
                    $mail->IsSMTP(true);
                    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
                    $mail->Username = '[*
                    $mail->Password
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                    $mail->Port = 587;
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                            'verify_peer' => false,
                            'verify_peer_name' => false,
                            'allow_self_signed' => true
                        )
                    );

                    $mail->setFrom('hideyourusername@nerdi.org');
                    $mail->addAddress($email,$name);
                    $mail->Subject = "Please verify Email";
                    $mail->isHTML(true);
                    $mail->Body = "
                    Please click on the link bellow:<br><br>

                    <a href='http://localhost/Trying/confermation.php?email=$email&token=$token'>Click Here</a>
                    ";
                    if($mail->send())
                        $msg = "You have been registered! Please verify your email";
                    else
                        $msg = "Something went wrong! Please try again";
                }
        }
    }
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scszl.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

This needs to be 0. If it is anything besides 0, it will print out errors! :)

You also need to delete your username/password from your code so we cannot login to your account...!